# How to click on SELECT ROOM button on https://www.goibibo.com/hotels using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to click on the **Select Room** button on [this](https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/sterling-ooty-elk-hill-hotel-in-Ooty-2300020804682931682/?hquery=%7B%22ci%22:%2220200715%22,%22co%22:%2220200716%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v3%22%7D&hmd=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&cc=IN) web page using Selenium and Xpath. However none of the selectors that I have tried seem to work.

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Select')]
```

will not work as it is not unique.

Comment: Which Select Room do you want to click? If you say there are more? Give us more details.

Comment: @KunLun i was editing the question. I would like to click on the first. This is a hotel booking website and upon entering location you get a list of options. we need to select the first option, which gives brings up the View N Rooms after that we need to click on Select Room on the first room shown. kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried `(//button[contains(text(), 'Select')])[1]`?

Comment: @KunLun yes, it does not seem to work when running the script.

Comment: Can you show us the code you try to run?

Comment: I have just tested you xpath with chromedriver and everything seems to work. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: xpath locator you are using is pointing to same button instance. Now I don't know which one is the active try all 3 locators.    (//button[contains(text(), 'Select')])[1]       (//button[contains(text(), 'Select')])[2]   (//button[contains(text(), 'Select')])[3].    Use JavascriptExecutor to click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Xpath of the "Select Room" button?

```
#try this
#insert the xpath of the "Select Room" button element

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>SELECT ROOM</kbd> button for the first *Room Type* you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/sterling-ooty-elk-hill-hotel-in-Ooty-2300020804682931682/?hquery=%7B%22ci%22:%2220200715%22,%22co%22:%2220200716%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v3%22%7D&hmd=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&cc=IN");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class^='RoomFlavorstyles__ButtonWrapper']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/sterling-ooty-elk-hill-hotel-in-Ooty-2300020804682931682/?hquery=%7B%22ci%22:%2220200715%22,%22co%22:%2220200716%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v3%22%7D&hmd=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&cc=IN");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Select')]"))).click();
  ```